pyuic generating file with C++ operator ::
I am using a make file to call pyuic module to convert QT's .ui file to .py in a virtual env. The generated file is having C++ operator :: in it.
The make file looks like this
all:
pyuic5 uaclient/mainwindow_ui.ui -o uaclient/mainwindow_ui.py

The version of pyqt5 in virtual env is 5.15.11.
Edit:
https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-client-gui/blob/master/uaclient/mainwindow_ui.ui
I created environment using anaconda, if that can be contributing to the issue in any way.

Please provide a ui file that reproduces the problem.

https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/opcua-client-gui/blob/master/uaclient/mainwindow_ui.ui

I cannot reproduce it, using either PyQt-5.15.11 or PyQt-6.7.1 on Linux. What version is shown in the comment at the top of the generated py file? And which specific members have the ::? Bugs like this have occured in some earlier versions of PyQt (not sure which ones). The pyuic5 called in the Makefile is probably from some other version of PyQt installed on your system.

Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.11
The DocWidget, focus policy in PushButton e.g.
[
self.addrDockWidget.setFeatures(QtCore.Qt.QDockWidget::DockWidgetFeature::NoDockWidgetFeatures)
self.addrDockWidget.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.Qt::DockWidgetArea::TopDockWidgetArea)
self.connectButton.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.Qt::FocusPolicy::StrongFocus)
]

Somehow, you must be looking at the wrong input file. If you search in the ui file linked in your question for e.g. Qt::FocusPolicy::StrongFocus, you will see that it does not appear anywhere. Qt5 Designer will always produce e.g. Qt::StrongFocus - which is exactly what appears in the file you provided. The real ui file your make-file is using must have been created by Qt6 Designer. There is a known problem with version 6.7.0 and greater, so you must re-save the ui files using an earlier version of Designer (preferrably Qt5).

You are right, I was opening the UI file in Qt creator which had Qt6 to look at layout and then calling the make command. Opening and saving the file in creator with Qt5 helped. Thank You.

Could not find it in Qt known issues wiki page though.

It's been reported on the pyqt mailing list a few times: see here and here.
